# Mac spawn startosinstall process with node.js

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm trying to spawn the startosinstall binary to begin a macOS upgrade. However, I'm seeing startosinstall binary run as root but then a sub process osinstallersetupd gets invoked but seems to run under my standard user account and not root.

Ultimately it breaks the automation because I get hit with an administrative authentication prompt.
[auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtYZi.png)

Showing the processes: [grep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od2zf.png)

Is this likely an Apple bug/limitation or could it be related to the way of invoking the first binary?

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

child = spawn("/Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall",
    [
        "--applicationpath",
        "/Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app",
        "--agreetolicense"
    ],
    {
        //maybe try some config options?
    }
);

child.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString() + "\n");
});

child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString() + "\n");
});

child.on("exit", (code, signal) => {
    console.log("child process exited: " + code + "\n");
});
```

For what it's worth I'm logged in as root and running the script above.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the issue. I am using parts of a script that helps in facilitating upgrades and found that when using the FileVault authenticated reboots you create and load a plist.

macOSUpgrade: https://github.com/kc9wwh/macOSUpgrade/blob/master/macOSUpgrade.sh#L278

However, it seems I was not actually loading the plist and that caused an issue.

tl;dr I wasn't loading the plist: https://github.com/kc9wwh/macOSUpgrade/blob/master/macOSUpgrade.sh#L337